# ToC affected by titleformat

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, titletoc

Thanks to Bernard i was able to accomplish this look:[image]  which is what I was looking for. Though, my ToC is also affected by this: [image], and I would like to make my ToC look normal, like nothing has happened to it. I wrote titleformat in order to get the look from the first picture, but is there a way which configures the ToC look so that it can look normal? My coding looks like this:

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]{ \scshape \bfseries }{}
{3ex}
{{\fontsize{149}{50}\selectfont \color{ForestGreen} \thesection}\quad \Huge}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2in}{10ex}
```

Thanks, and happy new year!

Comment: `\tableofcontents` uses `\section*` (in an article - like class), your `\titleformat` does not take care of `\section*`, but is a sledge-hammer for all `\section` macros, `\section` is basically a wrapper for more code that checks whether it is the `\section*` or the real unstarred version of it.

Comment: A solution is to shift the `\titleformat` content **after** `\tableofcontents`. And please post complete code, not only fragments

Comment: Christian Hupfer's solution worked, thanks a lot. Happy New Year!

Comment: Please see what I've added to my answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 1):

The number (the label in the terminology of titlesec) belongs in the third argument of titleformat:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\titleformat{\section}
            {\scshape \bfseries}
            {\fontsize{149}{50}\selectfont \color{ForestGreen} \thesection}
            {20pt}
            {\Huge}

%\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2in}{10ex}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{abc}
blblbl

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! My mistake, happy new year! :)